# How to make sure stored procedure executes correctly?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a stored procedure. I want to send some values to the stored procedure. Below are the parameters

```
@CorporateId Input
@CitizenId   Input
@DocType     Input
@Revert      Input
@ResponseCode Out
@ResponseMessage Out
```

I need to send values for `CorporateId` ,`CitizenId`,`DocType` and `@Revert` where the value is 0 always.  when inserting documents I want to send 0 as a value to `@rever`.

Sample code I've tried

```
 public EmployeeDetail InsertDocumentFlagRevert(int? corporateID, string citizenId, int? docType, string connectingString)
 {
     string constring = connectingString;
     EmployeeDetail objclValues = new EmployeeDetail();

     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
     {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uup_Employee_KYC_Uploaded_Flag", con))
         {
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

             if (corporateID == null)
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorporateID", DBNull.Value);
             }
             else
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorporateID", corporateID);
             }

             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(citizenId))
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenId", DBNull.Value);
             }
             else
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenId", citizenId);
             }

             if (docType == null)
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocType", DBNull.Value);
             }
             else
             {
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocType", docType);
             }

             cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResponseCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2);
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResponseMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 70);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Revert", 0);

             cmd.Parameters["@ResponseCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
             cmd.Parameters["@ResponseMessage"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

             con.Open();
             int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             con.Close();
         }
     }
 }
```

In this code, the value for i is -1. I am not sure if the parameters are actually being passed to the stored procedure or not? Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Use profiler to catch the execution statement and then using that you can debug the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected.

Try Commenting the `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure.
This will return the number of affected rows. I hope this will help you resolve the issue.

Comment: I did not put SET NOCOUNT ON in my sp.

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON` is not used for this purpose. When you run a query, the SSMS provides you details of how many rows have been effected. Setting nocount on will prevent that message, as that is only helpful when you are executing queries directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use SQL Profiler to inspect the query sent with parameters from your application to SQL Server.

Or, you can use the two output variables and inspect its values to make sure the parametres were sent correctly, the least is to append the parameter values in the `@ResponseMessage` parameter and check its value after the call for `ExecuteNonQuery` method

Comment: I am able to return @ResponseMessage from the above SP